# Find string then from there pull numbers

Tags: bash

Im starting to code bash and not the best but i have a situation. I have an output like:

```
Configuration file 'hello2.conf' is in use by process 735.
Ending
```

I want to extract the process ID `735`.
I seen answers were to extract ONLY numbers from outputs but then i am left with `2735`?

How can i go about extracting `735` from the output? I was thinking search for `process` then grab number after perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GNU grep` with its [Perl Compatible Regular Expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) capabilities enabled with the `-P` flag and print only the matching entry using `-o` flag.

```
grep -Po 'process \K[0-9]+' <<<"Configuration file 'hello2.conf' is in use by process 735."
735
```

Use it in a command line as

```
.. | grep -Po 'process \K[0-9]+'
```

where the `\K` escape sequence stands for

> \K: [This sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hxwGPA/1)

Comment: How would i execute this like? Would it be: `output="noip2 -C | grep -Po 'process \K[0-9]+'"
eval $output`

Comment: @irishwill200: Just do, `output=$(noip2 -C  | grep -Po 'process \K[0-9]+')` and to output the value, `echo "$output"`

Comment: Thanks! But i only receive `Configuration file 'hello2.conf' is in use by process 735.
Ending!`

Comment: @irishwill200: Can you post the full output of `noip2 -C`?

Comment: Full output is: `[root@root ~]# noip2 -C

Configuration file 'hello2.conf' is in use by process 735.
Ending!

[root@root ~]#` Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a regular expressions:

```
[[ "$line" =~ ([0-9]+)\.$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This should match any number at the end of the line, select the number part, and print it!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you line remains the same, use `cut -d" " -f 9`

Comment: This would include the "." at the end of the line, and not ensure that the last element is a number...

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can extract only the numbers at the specific location of the message (using `\(...\)` match grouping and `\1` replacement).

```
... | sed "s@^Configuration file '.*' is in use by process \([0-9]*\)\.@\1@"
```